# trigger named component on click and manage click off element

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a `Dropdown.vue` component. It has a prop called `name` so that I can trigger it using any div I want with a click event.

For example, I have an element `<button @click="openDropdown('notifications-dropdown')">test</test>`

then I have the component: `<dropdown name="notifications-dropdown"><div>content</div></dropdown>`

The click event is being handled from the global Vue object in methods:

```
methods: {
        openDropdown( name) {
            EventBus.$emit('dropdown-opened', name);
        }
    }
```

On the actual Dropdown component, I have in the Mounted method:

```
EventBus.$on('dropdown-opened', (name) => {
 if (this.name == name) {
    this.active = true;
 }
});
```

This all works fine, however, I need to handle the click off element functionality so that when the dropdown isn't being clicked, the `active` boolean is changed to false.

on dropdown, I have:

```
methods: {
        closeDropdown(e) {
            if ( !this.$el.contains(e.target) ) {
                this.active = false;
            } 
        }
    }
```

and in `mounted` and `beforeDestroy`, I have:

`document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeDropdown)`

**The issue then becomes, on the initial button click that is triggering the dropdown also triggers event click off element. so the dropdown opens and immediately closes**

How can I make it so on the initial button click that triggers the dropdown doesn't also trigger the off `e.target` click `closeDropdown()`.

But then if you click the trigger again, I'd expect the dropdown to close.

Below is the full code:

`Dropdown.vue`

```
<template>
    <Transition name="fade-in-scale">
        <div @click.stop ref="thedropdown" v-if="active" class="dropdown-menu absolute bg-white border-l border-b border-r border-gray-200 top-100  w-72 right-0 md:w-84">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </Transition>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src

export default {

    name: 'Dropdown',
    data() {
        return {
            active: false
        }
    },
    props: {
        name: String
        
    },
    computed: {
      
    },
    mounted() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.closeDropdown);

        EventBus.$on('dropdown-opened', (name) => {
            if (this.name == name) {
                this.active = !this.active;
            }
        });
       
    },

    beforeDestroy () {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeDropdown)
    },

    watch: {
        
    },
    methods: {
        closeDropdown(e) {
            if ( !this.$el.contains(e.target) ) {
                this.active = false;
            } 
        }
    }
}
</script>


<style lang="scss" scoped>

    .dropdown-menu {
        top:calc(100% + 5px);
    }

    .fade-in-scale-enter-active,
    .fade-in-scale-leave-active {
        transition: all 0.12s;
        transform:scale(1) ;
        opacity:1;
    }
    .fade-in-scale-enter,
    .fade-in-scale-leave-to {
        transform: scale(0.90);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
</style>
```

`app.blade.php`

```
<button @click="openDropdown('notifications-dropdown')" type="button" class="p-2 outline-none focus:outline-none"></button>
<dropdown name="notifications-dropdown"></dropdown>
```

`app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * UI
 */
import Btn from './components/ui/Button.vue';
import Dropdown from './components/ui/Dropdown.vue';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
       Btn,
       Dropdown
    },
    methods: {
        openDropdown( name) {
            EventBus.$emit('dropdown-opened', name);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.stop` event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) on the opening button's `@click` so that the event's propagation is stopped and does not reach the document's `click` handler:

```html
<button @click.stop="openDropdown(...)">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-dropdown-troubleshoot?file=src/App.vue)

Also be aware of the memory leak in `Dropdown.vue`, as it does not remove the event listener from the event bus. This is easily fixed by declaring a component method for `openDropdown`, and using that to add the event listener in `mounted` and to remove it in `beforeDestroy`:

```js
export default {
    mounted() {
        EventBus.$on('dropdown-opened', this.openDropdown);
    },

    beforeDestroy () {
        EventBus.$off('dropdown-opened', this.openDropdown)
    },

    methods: {
        openDropdown(name) {/*...*/}
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. I was worried I'd have to rethink how I was doing things. I'll have to look into memory leaks and Vue. I've added the mounted and beforeDestroy methods. Thank you thank you!

Comment: Why do you use an event bus to open the dropdown? I would just put a template ref on the dropdown to call its `openDropdown` method.

Comment: Initially I was creating a separate component for every dropdown. I'm going back and refactoring components so elements can simply call a dropdown that uses slots. Can you show me an example of what you mean? I only used the bus because I don't know of another way to globally call a specific instance of a component. still pretty new to vue and have bad habits

Comment: Scoped slots is definitely the way to go.

Comment: A quick refactor would be for the parent to put a template ref on the dropdown (`<dropdown ref="dropdown">`), and calling its `openDropdown` method from the opening button's `click`-handler (`<button @click="$refs.dropdown.openDropdown()">Open</button>`)

Comment: ah wow interesting. that works great and now I can get rid of my event bus method (which did feel janky). really appreciate your help. I guess one final thing with the new method of using the ref is, how can I close all other instances when a new one is opened?

Comment: @good_afternoon The event bus you have here might be the simplest solution if there is only one group active at once. Otherwise if multiple dropdown groups can be active, where each group allows only 1 open dropdown, that might require a wrapper component that tracks the dropdown groups separately (like in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-dropdown-accordion?file=src%2FApp.vue)). I'll propose that as an answer in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68056328/6277151) at some point.