# Get all instances of a vue component and run a function on each

Tags: vue.js

I have a component called `Dropdown`.

I trigger specific instances with a click event:

`<button @click.stop="$refs.notificationsDropdown.toggleDropdown()"></button>`

triggers

`<dropdown ref="notificationsDropdown"></dropdown>`

the `toggleDropdown` function simply changes a boolean value in the `data` which shows a div if `true`.

Before this value is set to true, I'd like to get all instances of `Dropdown` and set this value to false so that all other dropdowns close before the new one opens.

How can I get all instances of `Dropdown` and run a function on each of them to close their dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Vuex state](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) can help. You can change boolean value in `data` to `compute` value.
In dropdown:

```js
  computed: {
    isShowed: function() {
      return this.$store.state.activeDropdown === this;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDropdown: function() {
      if (this.$store.state.activeDropdown === this) {
        this.$store.state.activeDropdown = null;
      } else {
        this.$store.state.activeDropdown = this;
      }
    }
  }
```